# Why does the r session break when I try to make a prediction with a lightGBM model saved as ".rds"?

Tags: r, predict, lightgbm, tidymodels

After fitting a lightGBM model with tidymodels and treesnip, I can take the fitted workflow and make predictions on new data without any problems. However, after saving the adjusted model in ".rds" format, closing the session and loading the ".rds" model in a new session, when I try to generate a prediction the R session breaks.

This only happens with the lightGBM model, for any other type of model this inconvenience does not happen. Here is a reproducible example:

The lightGBM model was installed as follows

```
PKG_URL <- "https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/releases/download/v3.0.0/lightgbm-3.0.0-r-cran.tar.gz"
remotes::install_url(PKG_URL)
```

```
library(dplyr)
library(parsnip)
library(rsample)
library(yardstick)
library(recipes)
library(workflows)
library(dials)
library(tune)
library(treesnip)

data = bind_rows(iris, iris, iris, iris, iris, iris, iris)

set.seed(2)
initial_split <- initial_split(data, p = 0.75)
train <- training(initial_split)
test  <- testing(initial_split)
initial_split
#> <Analysis/Assess/Total>
#> <788/262/1050>

recipe <- recipe(Sepal.Length ~ ., data = data) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal(), -all_outcomes())

model <- boost_tree(
  mtry = 3, 
  trees = 1000, 
  min_n = tune(), 
  tree_depth = tune(),
  loss_reduction = tune(), 
  learn_rate = tune(), 
  sample_size = 0.75
) %>% 
  set_mode("regression") %>%
  set_engine("lightgbm")

wf <- workflow() %>% 
  add_model(model) %>% 
  add_recipe(recipe)

wf
#> ══ Workflow ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
#> Preprocessor: Recipe
#> Model: boost_tree()
#> 
#> ── Preprocessor ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> 1 Recipe Step
#> 
#> ● step_dummy()
#> 
#> ── Model ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Boosted Tree Model Specification (regression)
#> 
#> Main Arguments:
#>   mtry = 3
#>   trees = 1000
#>   min_n = tune()
#>   tree_depth = tune()
#>   learn_rate = tune()
#>   loss_reduction = tune()
#>   sample_size = 0.75
#> 
#> Computational engine: lightgbm

# resamples
resamples <- vfold_cv(train, v = 3)

# grid
grid <- parameters(model) %>% 
  finalize(train) %>% 
  grid_random(size = 10)

head(grid)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>   min_n tree_depth   learn_rate loss_reduction
#>   <int>      <int>        <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1     2          4 0.000282          0.0000402
#> 2    13         10 0.00333          13.0      
#> 3    32         11 0.000000585       0.000106 
#> 4    32          7 0.000258          0.163    
#> 5    31         13 0.0000000881      0.000479 
#> 6    19         14 0.000000167       0.00174


# grid search
tune_grid <- wf %>%
  tune_grid(
    resamples = resamples,
    grid = grid,
    control = control_grid(verbose = FALSE),
    metrics = metric_set(rmse)
  )


# select best hiperparameter found
best_params <- select_best(tune_grid, "rmse")
wf <- wf %>% finalize_workflow(best_params)

wf
#> ══ Workflow ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
#> Preprocessor: Recipe
#> Model: boost_tree()
#> 
#> ── Preprocessor ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> 1 Recipe Step
#> 
#> ● step_dummy()
#> 
#> ── Model ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Boosted Tree Model Specification (regression)
#> 
#> Main Arguments:
#>   mtry = 3
#>   trees = 1000
#>   min_n = 13
#>   tree_depth = 10
#>   learn_rate = 0.00333377440294304
#>   loss_reduction = 13.0320661814971
#>   sample_size = 0.75
#> 
#> Computational engine: lightgbm

# last fit
last_fit <- last_fit(wf,initial_split)

# metrics
collect_metrics(last_fit)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   .metric .estimator .estimate
#>   <chr>   <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1 rmse    standard       0.380
#> 2 rsq     standard       0.837

# fit to predict new data
model_fit <-  fit(wf, data)
#> [LightGBM] [Warning] Auto-choosing row-wise multi-threading, the overhead of testing was 0.000020 seconds.
#> You can set `force_row_wise=true` to remove the overhead.
#> And if memory is not enough, you can set `force_col_wise=true`.
#> [LightGBM] [Info] Total Bins 95
#> [LightGBM] [Info] Number of data points in the train set: 1050, number of used features: 5
#> [LightGBM] [Info] Start training from score 5.843333
#> [LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
#> [LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
#> [LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
#> [LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
#> [LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
#> [LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
#> [LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
#> [LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
#> [LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
#> [LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
#> [LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
#> [LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
#> [LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
#> [LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
#> [LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
#> [LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
#> [LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
#> [LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
#> [LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
.................................................................................
predicciones = predict(model_fit, iris)

head(predicciones)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 1
#>   .pred
#>   <dbl>
#> 1  5.13
#> 2  5.12
#> 3  5.12
#> 4  5.12
#> 5  5.13
#> 6  5.25

# save model
saveRDS(model_fit, "model_fit.rds")
```

After saving the model, I close the session and in a new session load the model.

```
model <- readRDS("model_fit.rds")

predicciones = predict(model, iris)
```

When I try to generate the prediction the r session breaks. An alternative that works mostly is to pull the workflow, extract the fit and save with the model's own method, however I lose all the workflow stored in the work_flow. I will be attentive to any help or suggestion.

```
pull_lightgbm = pull_workflow_fit(model_fit)


library(lightgbm)

lgb.save(pull_lightgbm$fit, "lightgbm.model")

model = lgb.load("lightgbm.model")
```

```
sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
#> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
#> Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRblas.dylib
#> LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#>  [1] treesnip_0.1.0.9000 tune_0.1.1          dials_0.0.9        
#>  [4] scales_1.1.1        workflows_0.2.1     recipes_0.1.14     
#>  [7] yardstick_0.0.7     rsample_0.0.8       parsnip_0.1.4      
#> [10] dplyr_1.0.2        
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] Rcpp_1.0.5         lubridate_1.7.9    lattice_0.20-41    tidyr_1.1.2       
#>  [5] listenv_0.8.0      class_7.3-17       assertthat_0.2.1   digest_0.6.27     
#>  [9] ipred_0.9-9        foreach_1.5.1      parallelly_1.21.0  R6_2.5.0          
#> [13] plyr_1.8.6         evaluate_0.14      ggplot2_3.3.2      highr_0.8         
#> [17] pillar_1.4.6       rlang_0.4.8        DiceDesign_1.8-1   furrr_0.2.1       
#> [21] rpart_4.1-15       Matrix_1.2-18      rmarkdown_2.5      splines_4.0.3     
#> [25] gower_0.2.2        stringr_1.4.0      munsell_0.5.0      compiler_4.0.3    
#> [29] xfun_0.19          pkgconfig_2.0.3    globals_0.13.1     htmltools_0.5.0   
#> [33] nnet_7.3-14        tidyselect_1.1.0   tibble_3.0.4       prodlim_2019.11.13
#> [37] codetools_0.2-16   GPfit_1.0-8        fansi_0.4.1        future_1.20.1     
#> [41] crayon_1.3.4       withr_2.3.0        MASS_7.3-53        grid_4.0.3        
#> [45] gtable_0.3.0       lifecycle_0.2.0    magrittr_1.5       pROC_1.16.2       
#> [49] cli_2.1.0          stringi_1.5.3      timeDate_3043.102  ellipsis_0.3.1    
#> [53] lhs_1.1.1          generics_0.1.0     vctrs_0.3.4        lava_1.6.8.1      
#> [57] iterators_1.0.13   tools_4.0.3        glue_1.4.2         purrr_0.3.4       
#> [61] parallel_4.0.3     survival_3.2-7     yaml_2.2.1         colorspace_1.4-1  
#> [65] knitr_1.30
```

Created on 2020-11-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) (v0.3.0)

Comment: Hi @Rafael, this is probably an issue with treesnip. Can you file an issue in the github repo? Best, Daniel

Comment: Perfect, thanks @DanielFalbel  the issue is already loaded in git.

Answer (score 0):

For others that may come across this post in the future:

- The [bonsai package](https://github.com/tidymodels/bonsai) follows up on the treesnip package and fixes many of the issues with LightGBM that you may be seeing.
- The development version of the lightgbm R package [supports saving with `saveRDS()`/`readRDS()`](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/pull/4685) as normal, and will be hitting CRAN in the next few months, so this will "just work" soon.
- Generally, if you're not sure whether a model object requires native serialization methods to safely save/reload in new sessions, you can use the [bundle](https://github.com/rstudio/bundle) package to prepare model objects for saving.